# How to show image title instead of icon in xcode code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, icons

I'm writing a pretty simple line, but it's hard for me to see what I've actually written, because my image title is displayed as an icon in xcode.

I want to see it as:

```
thing.image = picture.png
```

But instead I see it as:

```
thing.image = an actual icon is here in the code for some weird purpose I can't understand
```

I've searched with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**edit: I'm assuming it's an icon placeholder... it displays as a small white box.

**edit: here's a ss of how my code looks:

[image]

Comment: Any screenshots?

Comment: What's the image title ?, try changing your image title

Comment: they are Literals, if you want to use image name then you can do it like `UIImage(named: "picture")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**assign image to the UIImageView**

```
thing.image = UIImage(named:"picture.png")
```

Answer (score 10):

Related: I like the literals; to find out the name of the image after-the-fact, have Xcode reveal the name of the image asset by selecting the literal, then press `Cmd-E`, "Use Selection for Find". The image's name will show in the Find bar, e.g. `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icn_spinner")`

Alternatively, press `Cmd-/` to comment the line out; the commented form contains the literal text.

Comment: The comment approach actually allows you to edit the value.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight image and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, then the image name will be in the toolbar.